# Did a racer on a "restless" course race at some particular average velocity? (1: Starting blocks, finish line moving uniformly wrt. each o.)

Tags: velocity, geometry

Consider two participants, $A$ and $B$ moving uniformly wrt. each other; first having approached each other, then having met and passed each other, and eventually having separated from each other such that their mutual speed wrt. each other is given quantitatively as $\beta ~ c$ with some particular positive real number value $\beta < 1$. (Evidently, therefore, $A$ and $B$ had not been at rest to each other.)

After having observed $B$'s passage, $A$ has been preparing [starting blocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starting_blocks);
and at duration $\mathop{\Delta}\limits_{\stackrel{\normalsize{\text{until}}}{\small{\text{start}}}} \! \tau_A$ after having observed $B$'s passage, $A$ issued a starting signal to a racer ($R$) upon which the racer took off from $A$'s starting blocks.

After having observed $A$'s passage (i.e. soon enough after that), $B$ has been preparing a [finish line](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22finish+line%22+%22ribbon%22&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=KA8VU8ySIKPkywPv6oE4&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ&biw=932&bih=479);
and at duration $\mathop{\Delta}\limits_{\stackrel{\normalsize{\text{until}}}{\small{\text{finish}}}} \! \tau_B$ after having observed $A$'s passage, $B$'s finish line ribbon was passed by $R$.

The ratio of those durations is given as some particular positive real number value:

$r := \mathop{\Delta}\limits_{\stackrel{\normalsize{\text{until}}}{\small{\text{finish}}}} \! \tau_B ~ / ~ \mathop{\Delta}\limits_{\stackrel{\normalsize{\text{until}}}{\small{\text{start}}}} \! \tau_A$

which (of course) satisfies

$r > \sqrt{\frac{1 + \beta}{1 - \beta}}$.

**Question:**

Can an "[average velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity#Distinction_between_speed_and_velocity)" of racer $R$ with respect to the [race course, as far as it is specified by $A$'s starting blocks and $B$'s finish line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_course) be defined,
such that its magnitude could be expressed in terms of the given quantities $\beta ~ c$, $\beta$ and $r$
(and where its direction is obviously "from $A$ to $B$") ?

Comment: This is really convoluted.  I'm really not sure what you're getting at.

Comment: Brandon Enright: "_This is really convoluted. I'm really not sure what you're getting at._" -- Well: The "less-than-600-characters-version-without-any-math" goes like this: **Starting blocks $A$ and finish line $B$ are moving uniformly away from each other. Racer $R$ started from $A$ and arrived at $B$. How is "average velocity of racer $R$ with respect to [race course $AB$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_course)" defined, in a precise sense, if at all?**. My question is expressed so the required "math" is provided in a suitably precise sense, too; I'm afraid I couldn't leave that out ...